# split string from a string by sql

Tags: sql

I have this type of data in a column in my table,,,

```
QCIM1J77477, 4650125572, QCCR1J77891, 4650312729, QCCR1J74974 --- remove without comma
```

or

```
QCIM1E107498,QCIM1E109835,4650092399/ QCCR1E91190,  -- remove 4650092399
```

I want only that string which starts from QC,remove apart from QC,
so please tell me how can I achive it?

Comment: Did u tried something? Mention which DBMS u r using? Oracle,MySql?

Comment: replace_regexp something... (Product specific!)

Comment: I don't have a special value..can you please write that query for that without using regexp function??/

Comment: Database please! unless you want it to be done on flat file!

Comment: please post desired output

Comment: like : QCIM1E107498,QCIM1E109835,4650092399/ QCCR1E91190,                 output will be QCIM1E107498,QCIM1E109835,QCCR1E91190,

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 1):

Beneath a piece of `t-sql` script that  creates a temporary table #t with temporary variables. Here the temporary table exists untill you break your session, temporary variables exist during the execution of the script. I have a drop table statement at the bottom. Figure out yourself what you want with the table data and whether you want the data put in somewhere else, for example in a not-temporary table :).

I assume you want all the pieces of the string that contain 'QC' as seperate values. If you want your data back as it was originally, that is multiple strings per one column, then you could also do a group by trick. Then you do need a unique identifier of some sort, like name, id, guid of each row or identity.

```
create table #t ([QCs] nvarchar(100))

declare @str    nvarchar(500)
set @str = 'QCIM1E107498,QCIM1E109835,4650092399/ QCCR1E91190'
--replace the above temporary variable with the column you are selecting

declare @sql nvarchar(4000)
select @sql = 'insert into #t select '''+ replace(@str,',',''' union all select ''') + ''''
print @sql

exec ( @sql )

select
QCs
,PATINDEX('%QC%',QCs) as StartPosition
,SUBSTRING(QCs,PATINDEX('%QC%',QCs),12) as QCsNew
from #t where QCs like '%QC%'

drop table #t
```

With `PATINDEX` you find the position where in the string 'QC' starts, and with `SUBSTRING` you tell the dbms to give back (here) 12 characters starting from the found StartPosition.

Beneath what the result looks like. QCsNew is your desired result.

```
QCs                      StartPosition      QCsNew
QCIM1E107498             1                  QCIM1E107498
QCIM1E109835             1                  QCIM1E109835
4650092399/ QCCR1E91190 13                  QCCR1E91190
```

Comment: its fine but in any case we have this type of value :QCIM1E107498,QCIM1E109835,4650092399/ QCCR1E91190, than its not working f9,..here output will be QCIM1E107498,QCIM1E109835,QCCR1E91190,

Comment: I think that adding SUBSTRING in the latter part of the script will do the trick, which does something like: search for QC value and give x number of characters from there.  I can write it later for you or tomorrow.

Comment: @vipin-singhal: I made an addition to the script. This will work for the possibilities you've given in you rquestion. With PATINDEX you find the position where in the string 'QC' starts, and with SUBSTRING you tell the dbms to give back here 12 characters starting from the found StartPosition.

Comment: PS: you could add a label of your dbms (SQL Server?) and add a desired result in a list, to make more clearly what you want.